# How to know which selector is the active one?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-autocomplete

I've got the following (partial) code:

```
$("#input1, #input2").autocomplete({
   source:function( request, response ) { 
     ...
   }, ...);
```

Ok, I want to know how can I know which is the selector active, input1 or input2, inside the source option. I've tried with $(this).attr("id"), but it throws undefined.

Edition: in the "select:" option, $(this).attr("id") works fine.

Comment: Which jquery autocomplete plugin are you using?

Comment: jquery ui autocomplete, but I suspect it does no matter...

Comment: @elvenbyte: It would matter a lot, the answer depends entirely on the implementation of the autocompleter plug-in.

Comment: Yes..., this I'm afraid of..., thanks anyway. But, how does it know which element is working with? Internally I mean.

Comment: @elvenbyte: Internally, in the jQuery UI autocompleter, it's `this.element`. See my answer for details and suggestions for not relying on undocumented internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using the jQuery UI autocompleter, you can get the element from the ***undocumented*** `element` property on the autocompleter instance:

```
source: function(request, response) {
  if (this.element && this.element[0]) {
    display("source triggered for #" + this.element[0].id);
  }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ubunip)

`this.element` is a jQuery wrapper for the element the autocompleter is attached to, so `this.element[0]` is the raw DOM element.

But using undocumented information is always risky, it can change or go away between dot releases. It would be more reliable to use a closure as suggested by SadullahCeran. I'd do it slightly differently:

```
$("#input1, #input2").each(function(){
  var $element = $(this); // `element` is a jQuery wrapper around the element
  $(element).autocomplete({
   source:function( request, response ) { 
     // get the options relevant to `element`
   });
});
```

...just because then you're not relying on using an `id` value. But that's a small point. And yes, the above does end up creating two function objects, but that's not such a bad thing. If there's a lot of code involved and you're worried about having two copies of it in memory (which is almost certainly not an issue), just have the function call into another function:

```
$("#input1, #input2").each(function(){
  var $element = $(this); // `element` is a jQuery wrapper around the element
  $(element).autocomplete({
   source:function( request, response ) { 
     return getOptionsFor(element, request, response);
   });
});
function getOptionsFor(element, request, response) {
  // get the options for `element`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This workaround should be fine.
In source function of autocomplete plugin, $(this) may not refer to original jquery object.

```
$("#input1, #input2").each(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  // Do something with id if you want
  $(this).autocomplete({
   source:function( request, response ) { 
     // Source function
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the problem is that it's a really long code, and I just want to change one sentence. I don't want to repeat the code for both selectors... I'll try it anyway...

Comment: No, it doesn't enters the function, because I don't have the corresponding event associated...

Comment: There is a "selector" attribute in jquery object, But I'm sure you won't be able to get it, since $(this) object is not the jquery object you are looking for. May worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is $(this.element).attr("id"). Within the plugin (and for any callbacks you pass in) this generally refers to the ui widget object. I believe the aim is to standardise ui widgets so that, among other things, this.element will refer to the current DOM node whichever ui widget you use.

Comment: No, that's not the element I'm looking for. But I agree with you. "this" always should refer to de current DOM node.

Comment: @elvenbyte: Yes, it is, but it's undocumented. `this` is the autocompleter instance, and `this.element` is a jQuery wrapper around the element the autocompleter uses. See my answer for details. And agreed, `this` really should be the element, not the autocompleter.

Comment: I think it's best that this refers to the widget instance and not the dom element because that way you get direct access to all the widget's properties AND the DOM element. If "this" were the DOM element you'd have to use something like $(this).data("plugin_ui_autocomplete"), to get access to the actual widget